# How can I optimize this query? It should return the percent of values in a given constraint that are less than 40

Tags: sql-server

```
USE SIMDB
GO

SELECT Count([Xa])*1.0/
    (SELECT Count(*) FROM [dbo].[Simulations]
        WHERE [dbo].[Simulations].[ExperimentID] IN (
            SELECT [dbo].[Parameters].[ExperimentID] FROM [dbo].[Parameters] 
                WHERE [dbo].[Parameters].[SensorError] = 0 AND [dbo].[Parameters].[ExogDEXCurve] <> 4
                AND [dbo].[Parameters].[ControlRange] = 0)) AS XA_PIR0
    FROM [dbo].[Simulations]
    WHERE [dbo].[Simulations].[ExperimentID] IN (
            SELECT [dbo].[Parameters].[ExperimentID] FROM [dbo].[Parameters] 
                WHERE [dbo].[Parameters].[SensorError] = 0 AND [dbo].[Parameters].[ExogDEXCurve] <> 4
                AND [dbo].[Parameters].[ControlRange] = 0)
    AND [dbo].[Simulations].[Xa] <= 40

GO
```

This is a database containing simulation results from 90k simulations. The primary key in the `Parameters` table is `[ExperimentID]`, and the primary key in the `Simulations` table is a combination of `[ExperimentID]` and `[CycleCount]`, to uniquely identify rows within a given simulation. The total number of rows in the `Simulations` table is about 75 million. The `Simulations` table also has 21 columns, which it admittedly shouldn't. All indices are clustered.

This query takes ~23 minutes to run on my laptop, where the DB is stored. Checking the execution plan, there are two clustered index seeks, each of them taking 42%. Is this expected? How can I speed it up?

sqlplan here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gq1bl1wgmesh0bl/sqlplan.sqlplan?dl=0

Comment: The percentages are just estimates based on estimated number of rows. Check both statistics io output and estimated vs actual rows in actual plan to see if there's problems with estimations. Posting the query plan here is probably going to help

Comment: edited the OP with the plan

Comment: Looking at the query plan, are the estimated row counts even close being correct? Just guessing if there's 75 million rows in the table, it actually fetches a lot more than what it estimates

Comment: That's something that threw me off too. It's technically only selecting one row, but from ~75M. Not sure why that is.

Comment: It could be a cardinality estimation issue because of the parameters (SensorError, ExogDEXCurve, ControlRange) if those values are something you use often, creating a persistent computed column could help if it's indexed or other way might be using a temp table for ExperimentIDs, so optimizer might get better idea how many rows there are -- just in case it affects the plan

Comment: They're in their own table and use the same PK as Simulations; each simulation has a unique set of 6 parameters; I'm analysing the data over different sets of parameters. Short of making a temp table for every "interesting" set of parameters (probably gonna be like 300 sets), I'm not sure how else to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me that you can leave out the second select and do something like this:

```
select sum(1), sum(case when [Simulations].[Xa] <= 40 then 1 else 0 end)
FROM [dbo].[Simulations]
WHERE [dbo].[Simulations].[ExperimentID] IN (
    SELECT [dbo].[Parameters].[ExperimentID] 
    FROM [dbo].[Parameters] 
    WHERE [dbo].[Parameters].[SensorError] = 0
    AND [dbo].[Parameters].[ExogDEXCurve] <> 4
    AND [dbo].[Parameters].[ControlRange] = 0)
```

It might also help if you create index for Simulations with ExperimentID + Xa as included field, just so that there's less data to scan, since the table seems to be quite wide.

Comment: Wow, nice one! I think this is equivalent. Should at least half my execution time.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the shape of the data, optimization may be difficult.  However, this query may be easier to read and faster because it leverages MS SQL's set based engine.
Replace @simulationsTable and @parametersTable with your tables.  I used them to make things a easier to work with.

```
DECLARE @simulationsTable TABLE (
    ExperimentID INT
    ,Xa INT
    );
DECLARE @parametersTable TABLE (
    ExperimentID INT
    ,SensorError INT
    ,ExogDEXCurve INT
    ,ControlRange INT
    );

;WITH validParameters
AS (
    SELECT [ExperimentID]
    FROM @parametersTable
    WHERE [SensorError] = 0
        AND [ExogDEXCurve] <> 4
        AND [ControlRange] = 0
    )

SELECT COUNT([Xa]) * 1.0 / (sims.countOfSims) AS XA_PIR0
FROM @simulationsTable sim2
INNER JOIN validParameters p ON p.ExperimentID = sim2.ExperimentID
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT COUNT(1) AS countOfSims
    FROM @simulationsTable sim1
    INNER JOIN validParameters p ON p.ExperimentID = sim1.ExperimentID
    ) sims
WHERE [Xa] <= 40
GO
```

Additionally, if count of sims is the same for each row, you could just calculate it ahead of time and store the result.

```
 DECLARE @countOfSims INT = (
        SELECT COUNT(1) AS countOfSims
        FROM @simulationsTable sim1
        CROSS APPLY (
            SELECT[ExperimentID]
            FROM @parametersTable
            WHERE [SensorError] = 0 AND [ExogDEXCurve] <> 4 AND [ControlRange] = 0
        ) params
        WHERE params.ExperimentID = sim1.ExperimentID
);

--And then use the result in your query.

;WITH validParameters
AS (
    SELECT[ExperimentID]
    FROM @parametersTable
    WHERE [SensorError] = 0 AND [ExogDEXCurve] <> 4 AND [ControlRange] = 0
)

SELECT COUNT([Xa])*1.0/ ( @countOfSims ) AS XA_PIR0
    FROM @simulationsTable sim2
    INNER JOIN validParameters p on p.ExperimentID = sim2.ExperimentID

    WHERE [Xa] <= 40

GO
```

Comment: Is it possible then to select just a subtable for @similationstable?

Comment: in the code, just replace @@simulationsTable with dbo.Simulations, and @@parametersTable with dbo.Parmeters.  I've updated my answer to include another path if your count of simulations is a static value.

Answer (score 0):

Using EXISTS and index on dbo.Parameters table, you might reduce amount of data that needs to be read from it.

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN S.Xa <= 40 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 1.0 / SUM(1)
FROM dbo.Simulations AS S
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM dbo.Parameters AS P
        WHERE P.ExperimentID = S.ExperimentID
            AND P.SensorError = 0
            AND P.ExogDEXCurve <> 4
            AND P.ControlRange = 0
        );
```

Credits to [JamesZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4420967/jamesz) for providing a smart way to replace `COUNT` with `SUM`.

Also, I'd create couple of indexes on your tables using these statements. I'm sure they'll boost query execution time quite a lot:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_Parameters_SensorError_ExogDEXCurve_ControlRange_ExperimentID
    ON dbo.Parameters (SensorError, ExogDEXCurve, ControlRange, ExperimentID);

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_Simulations_ExperimentID_Xa
    ON dbo.Simulations (ExperimentID, Xa);
```

To be precise, this needs to be optimized. I'm guessing it takes most time to execute.

[image: Execution plan hint]